# Owl Carousel 2: Overflow at the bottom issue

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel-2

I have an issue with this excellent carousel, actually with overflow option at the bottom. My list items have a hidden part which becomes visible when you move your mouse on them. By default owl carousel has "overflow: hidden" and moving the mouse on an item in the list item won't show the hidden part, it is cut. Deleting the overflow option I can see the hidden part, but left and right items become visible. If anyone had this issue I appreciate for a solution.

Here is default behavior (overflow: hidden)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtWBl.jpg)

Here is what I need but without seeing left and right items (overflow: none)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POw6Y.jpg)